# Acquire Azure token from .Net Core 2.0 controller (Bearer)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-authentication

This is my startup.cs code

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddAzureAdBearer(configureOptions =>
{
    configureOptions.Instance = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AD_Instance");
    configureOptions.Domain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AD_Domain");
    configureOptions.TenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AD_TenantId");
    configureOptions.ClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AD_ClientId");
}
```

JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme is Bearer

These are my options:

```
public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
{
    options.Audience = _azureOptions.ClientId;
    options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false
    };
    options.SaveToken = true;
}
```

Now, according to many blogs and Questions & Answers here 
I use this code to retrieve the token: (Btw application works fine more than 6 months already, don't consider some set up issues)

```
var token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

And this is what it returns:

[image: Click for the image]

What I need is the access_token. ex. Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1...

**UPDATE:** 
After I saw the comments/answers I added await, but I get null as a result.

Comment: you need to await `var token =await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")` or wait synchronously `var token =_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: it's an async method , the token might not be available yet when you debugging it. Use await before

Comment: Yes, you are right, somehow I missed that, I added await but I get null as a result. Any idea why is that?

Comment: You need to update your question with the updated code and updated screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The method [`GetTokenAsync("access_token")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.gettokenasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions_GetTokenAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_System_String_) is asynchronous and is returning an `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>` result. So the `var` here is translating to:

```
Task<string> token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

In order to access the actual result, you need to unpack it from the Task. The easiest way to do this is to use the `await` keyword:

```
string token = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer @marc-lafleur and  yes, you are right, somehow I missed that, I added await but I get null as a result. Any idea why is that?